# How to add an option to the popup actionsheet of iphone safari?

Tags: iphone, safari

I am using UIWebview in my app, when tap and hold on a link for a second an actionsheet pops up with some options OPEN, COPY and Cancel.
How to add a custom option to the actionsheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.

---

The buttons in the popup action sheet are **hardcoded** for each data type. You can't change that from a web site. You can change the buttons by overriding various private methods in `UIWebDocumentView` and `UIWebURLAction`, but you can't do these in AppStore apps anyway since they are *undocumented* classes.

Comment: How can I access the private methods you mentioned?